# How can I overlay a text over another using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have this html file where I want to overlay some text over another. I tried to use the z-index property but can't get it to work. What is missing in my code?

thanks a lot

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#overlay {
    z-index:100;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id='overlay'>overlayed text</div>

This is some dummy text

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set `position: absolute`. The `z-index` applies to elements that aren't statically positioned (see BoltClock's comment).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#overlay {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id='overlay'>overlayed text</div>

This is some dummy text

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It applies to any elements that aren't statically positioned. That means `relative`, `absolute` and `fixed` all apply.

Comment: And if you position it like that, you don't even need the z-index.

Comment: In my case I didn't want to position it absolutely because the place on the page may change, so I position it absolutely but give its parent `position: relative;`.

Comment: Great solution!  I can also control whether the background text is left-aligned/right-aligned with normal CSS (in my case, float).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with CSS alone by making use of :before

```css
img.image:before {
    left: 0;
    content: "Coming Soon";
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.59);
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 2.5;
    font-weight: 600;
   position: absolute; 

}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer TBH, i've come here and used this couple of times yet i find it so useful

Comment: This is the best way to do it today.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only applies to elements with `position:relative` or `position:absolute`. In your case you'll be wanted to use `position:absolute` to place the overlayed text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. Indeed, absolute is what I need in this case. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-shadow` to achieve your result.

```css
h1 {
    display: block;
    color: #003366;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 52px;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-shadow: 2px -2px 0 #00FF99;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Awesome</h1>
</body>
</html>
```