# How to overlay a darker colour text on a brigther colour text?

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot of methods, position absolute on the text on the back, but it comes i front of the other text because i don't want to put on "What we offer" absolute aswell. I want a responsive method that allows me to hide the back text.

I will attach a photo below:

[image: photo full of text]

Comment: Could this article help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775853/how-can-i-overlay-a-text-over-another-using-css

Comment: maybe use z-index?

Comment: z-index works only if put relative on the parent and absolute on each individual text, but I don't feel it's a good practice to move one by one because i'm using bootstrap for positioning

Comment: @volpoh I already tried that method and it's not working for me, I have been trying for the past 3 hours to put that text behind

Comment: Can you create add some code?

Comment: Why doesn’t Cruisers being in an absolute positioned element work? Please show us the code where you tried that because it should be fine.

Comment: I'm sorry but i deleted it and tried numerous methods. The problem with the link above  is that Cruisers would be over both texts and i should put all 3 in an absolute position and then z-index. Isn't there any other method out there besides relative and absolute ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f2ec;
}

.main {
  padding: 60px 45px;
}

.main-title-block {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 45px 0 45px;
}

.back-text {
  color: #eee8df;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 116px;
  line-height: 124px;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.sub-heading {
  color: #ccb673;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-title {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-title-block">
    <h6 class="back-text">cruisers</h6>
    <span class="sub-heading">nautical company</span>
    <h1 class="main-title">what we offer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello Alin99,
To achieve your layout as per the image.

1. u need a relative block to keep all 3 heading(backtext,subheading and heading).
2. after that you need to set backtext to position:absolute; and set it's z-index:-1; as it enable to set back and absoluting it will help to set it positions with top,bottom,left and right as per your choice.

Here the key thing was to understand the use of position relative and position absolutes.
I have made `.main-title-block` relative, which sets boundary for it;s child absolute element(which is here `.back-text`).

Comment: Hi ! I have tried you method and with z-index : -1 it goes under the bg colour, and when i set z-index:0; it goes over the main title and sub-heading

Comment: It worked by adding z-index:0; to the main-title-block that is relative and z-index:-1; on back-text; I feel this working is a little bit strange

Comment: There might be chances that you have structured it in a way which changing this z-index behaviour, However if it's working than cheers..