# How can I overlay text behind the user input in an input element?

Tags: html, css

There is an input element that the user can input some things into, and I want to be able to add an overlay text behind it so it looks like a placeholder that doesn't get removed even if there is content in the input.

I obviously thought about a separate element, but I couldn't make it go between the background and the text of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Wrap `<input>` in a `<label>`
- `<label>` will have the text, `<input>` will have a transparent background.
- `<label>` occupies the lower *"layer"* and acts as the `<input>`'s border. Assign `position: relative` to the `<label>` and `position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0;` to `<input>` so that it sits *"above"* the `<label>`.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.25em 0.75em;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  vertical-align: sub;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

input {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1;
  background: transparent;
}

.top {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<label>This text belongs to the &lt;label&gt;<input></label>
<label class="top">Having the text in the middle is messy<input></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is your go to for this implementation. Make the position of both the divs absolute, and make sure they have the same absolute components.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775853/how-can-i-overlay-a-text-over-another-using-css) has a similar implementation.

Comment: The problem is, the background of the input hides the text beneath... Is there a way to compensate for that?